# Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool Error: Incorrect syntax near 'DISTRIBUTION'

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

The following code on Azure Synapse Serverless SQL Pool gives the following error:

Incorrect syntax near 'DISTRIBUTION'.

```
SELECT CM.EntityName,
    --Before the first column of each table, construct a DROP TABLE statement if already exist
    CASE WHEN CM.OrdinalPosition = 1
        THEN 
        'DROP EXTERNAL TABLE MyTable' + '.' + 
        QUOTENAME(@EnrichedViewSchema) + '.' + CM.EntityName + '
        CREATE TABLE MyTable' + '.' +
        QUOTENAME(@EnrichedViewSchema) + '.' + CM.EntityName + '
        WITH
        (
        DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
        );
        AS
        SELECT DISTINCT '
        ELSE '  ,'
        END
```

Can someone look at the code and let me know where I might going wrong?

Comment: Azure Synapse SQL Server Pool -- **Is it Synapse Serverless SQL pool?,**

Comment: Hi Aswan, yes it is Synapse Serverless SQL pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure Synapse SQL Server Pool Error: Incorrect syntax near 'DISTRIBUTION'

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable' + '.' +
        QUOTENAME(@EnrichedViewSchema) + '.' + 
        CM.EntityName + '
        WITH
        (
        DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
        )
```

- Serverless SQL pool is used to query over the data lake, and we cannot create tables in it. We can create external tables and temporary tables only in serverless SQL pool.
- Also, Distribution is applicable only for dedicated SQL pool tables.
  Therefore, above SQL script is not possible.

[image]
Reference: screenshot from Microsoft document [Design tables using Synapse SQL - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-overview)

Comment: your first bullet point is illogical ... it says serverless is query only then you say serverless allows create external and temp tables ... I believe you meant dedicated SQL pools

Answer (score 0):

there is an additional semicolon before AS in your script.

Wrong:
CREATE TABLE XXX WITH(DISTRIBUTION=ROUND_ROBIN); AS SELECT

Correct:
CREATE TABLE XXX WITH(DISTRIBUTION=ROUND_ROBIN) AS SELECT

Comment: Hi @Onur thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error after removing the additional semicolon ;

Comment: Any more thoughts on this SO members?